# enemy AI collision detection isn't working

Tags: pygame, artificial-intelligence, collision

My enemy AI isn't detecting collisions. I have been using the code that I use for my player collision detection. I tweaked it to fit the enemy, however it isn't working:

```
class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y,player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.image.fill(Color("#FF0000"))    #Enemy is red
        self.onGorund = False
            #Enemy is 32 * 32 pixels
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
        self.counter = 0    #counter variable
        self.player = player



    def move(self, speed = 5):    # chase movement
        if self.rect.x > self.player.rect.x:    # Movement along x direction 
            self.rect.x -= speed
        elif self.rect.x < self.player.rect.x:
            self.rect.x += speed
        if self.rect.y < self.player.rect.y:    # Movement along y direction
            self.rect.y += speed
        elif self.rect.y > self.player.rect.y:
            self.rect.y -= speed

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, Player_class):
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print ("collide right")
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print ("collide left")
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

    def update(self, platforms):
        if up:

            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10    #only jump if player is on the ground
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:

            self.yvel += 0.3    #only accelerate with gravity if in the air

            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100    #terminal velocity = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        self.rect.left += self.xvel    #falls or jumps

        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)    #creates collisions along the x axis

        self.rect.top += self.yvel    #creates collisions along the y axis

        self.onGround = False;    #assumes that the player is in the air
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)
```

I have been trying to make the window close whenever the enemy touches the player, problem being, if the enemy doesn't know that it's touching the player, it can't close the window. Please ask if more code is required.

Comment: *"Please ask if more code is required."* Yes, a [minimal but runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed.

- In the `move` method you should set the velocity (`self.xvel` and `self.yvel`) instead of moving the rect directly.
- Then call the `move` method in the `update` method, move the rect of the sprite and handle the collisions. Also, you need to call the `update` method in the `main` function now instead of `move` and pass the `platforms` list:

  ```
  enemy_list.draw(screen)
  for e in enemy_list:
      e.update(platforms)
  ```
- In the collide method you check if one of the platforms is the player instance:

  ```
  for p in platforms:
      if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
          if isinstance(p, Player_class):
              pygame.quit()
              sys.exit()
  ```

  However, the player sprite isn't in this list, so it can't collide.

  The enemy actually has a reference to the player (`self.player`) so you can just do this to check if they collide:

  ```
  if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player):
  ```

  or:

  ```
  if self.rect.colliderect(self.player.rect):
  ```

Here's a complete example (I took the code from your previous question and tried to improve a few more things):

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


win_height = 750    #height of window is 750 pixles
win_width = 1050    #height of window is 1050 pixels
half_win_width = int(win_width / 2)    #will be used to centre camera
half_win_height = int(win_height / 2)

display = (win_width, win_height)    #creates the window as 500*500 pixels
depth = 32    #prevents infinate recursion
flags = 0    #message to Les: I don't really know what this does, however I have seen it in many places being used, therefore I assumed that it was important
camera_slack = 30    #how many pixels the player can move before the camera moves with them

pygame.init()


def main():    #main game function
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, flags, depth)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Super Castlevania Man")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    move_cameraX = 0
    move_cameraY = 0

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    background = pygame.Surface((32,32))    #the background takes up space on the screen
    background.convert()
    background.fill(pygame.Color("#000000"))    #background is black
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player_class(32, 32*15)    #the player is 32*32 pixels large
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                               P",
        "P         E                     P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                    PPPPPPPPP  P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                               P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                   P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                          PPPP P",
        "P                 PPPPPP        P",
        "P         PPPPPPP               P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                     PPPPPP    P",
        "P                               P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                 P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP   P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                               P",
        "P                               P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",    
        ]
    #builds the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)    #makes P a solid object
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = Exit_block(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    entities.add(player)
    enemy = Enemy(60, 200, player)    #Spawns enemy
    enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()    #creates an enemy group
    enemy_list.add(enemy)    #Add an enemy to the group

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)    #makes game run at 60 frames per second

        for e in pygame.event.get():    #shortens event to e
            if e.type == QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
                move_cameraY = -10
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
                move_cameraY = 10
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
                move_cameraX = -10
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
                move_cameraX = 10
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
                move_cameraY = 0
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
                move_cameraY = 0
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
                move_cameraX = 0
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
                move_cameraX = 0
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False        

        # Update the game.
        for e in enemy_list:
            e.update(platforms)
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)

        # Draw everything.
        for y in range(32):    #draws the background
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(background, (x * 32, y * 32))
        entities.draw(screen)
        enemy_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()  # You need only one flip or update call per frame.


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):    #makes player a sprite
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)    #sets sprite to initiate


class Player_class(Entity):    #defines player class
    def __init__(self, x, y):    #x is the player x coordinate, y is the player y coordinate
        Entity.__init__(self)    #the player is an entity
        self.xvel = 0    #how fast the player is moving left and right
        self.yvel = 0    #how fast the player is moving up and down
        self.onGround = False    #assumes the player is in the air
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,32))    #the player is 32*32 pixels
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color("#0000FF"))    #makes the player blue
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel -= 10    #only jump if player is on the ground
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:

            self.yvel += 0.3    #only accelerate with gravity if in the air

            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100    #terminal velocity = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        self.rect.left += self.xvel    #falls or jumps

        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)    #creates collisions along the x axis

        self.rect.top += self.yvel    #creates collisions along the y axis

        self.onGround = False;    #assumes that the player is in the air
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, Exit_block):
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)


class Exit_block(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color("#FF7700"))#exit block is orange


class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y,player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color("#FF0000"))    #Enemy is red
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
        self.player = player

    def move(self, speed=5):    # chase movement
        if self.rect.x > self.player.rect.x:    # Movement along x direction 
            self.xvel = -speed
        elif self.rect.x < self.player.rect.x:
            self.xvel = speed
        if self.rect.y < self.player.rect.y:    # Movement along y direction
            self.yvel = speed
        elif self.rect.y > self.player.rect.y:
            self.yvel = -speed

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        # Check if the enemy collides with the player.
        if self.rect.colliderect(self.player.rect):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

    def update(self, platforms):
        self.move()  # Set the velocity.

        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)    #creates collisions along the x axis

        self.rect.top += self.yvel    #creates collisions along the y axis
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot :)